# Finding Eigenvectors, is there always a row of $0$'s?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Given the Matrix $$A = \left(\begin{matrix}
> 0 & 1 & 0 \\
> 0 & 0 & 1 \\
> -1 & -3 & -3
> \end{matrix}\right)$$
>
> calculate the eigenvalues and the corresponding eigenvectors.

**My attempt**

$$P(\lambda) = \det(A-\lambda I) = -\lambda^3-3\lambda^2-3\lambda-1 =0$$ is the characteristical polynome with the solutions $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=\lambda_3 = -1$

So there is only one eigenvalue $-1$

This involves solving $(A-(-1)I)= A+I = 0$.

> Is "the last row" always $0$ when calculating the eigenvectors?

**Update**

I've got the final answer to be $$E_{-1}=\left(\begin{matrix}1 \\ -1 \\ 1 \end{matrix}\right)$$

Comment: If one of the rows in the row reduction process did not become all zeros, then that would mean $(A+I)x=0$ has a unique solution. But $x=0$ obviously is a solution, so this would imply that there is no eigenvector, a contradiction. So, yeah, finding an eigenvector means that you need to find a non-trivial solution to a homogeneous system. So that special case of the algorithm for solving a linear system is a must.

Answer (score 3):

Given:

$$A = \left(\begin{matrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
-1 & -3 & -3
\end{matrix}\right)$$

We arrive at:

$$P(\lambda) = det(A-\lambda I) = -\lambda^3-3\lambda^2-3\lambda-1 =0$$ is the characteristical polynomial with the solutions $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=\lambda_3 = -1$

Solving for the eigenvectors, we arrive at::

$$\lambda_1 = -1, v_1 = (1, -1, 1)$$

$$\lambda_2 = -1, v_2 = (2, -1, 0)$$

$$\lambda_2 = -1, v_3 = (3,-1, 0)$$

From these eigenvalues and eigenvectors, the Jordan Normal Form can be written as:

$$A = P J P^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ -1 & -1 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ -1 & -3 & -2 \\ 1 & 2 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Regards

Comment: Nice work! All this work, and no prior thumbs up! Well, that's history, now. ;-)

Comment: Your welcome...I feel the same...and have deleted many posts...feeling they must not be/have been helpful. But if this is typical of your work (and your work IS helpful, period), then it has, and will likely help others, even if only to serve as an example for a similar problem.

Comment: @amWhy: you are correct, and I do think twice about as I have seen old answers get positive feedback at later times. I just hate clutter! :-) So, I am much more careful before I remove answers.